# VBA Type Mismatch Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to create a loop with VBA that will update the border color for a selected range. The loop is cycling through an array of each border I would like to update. This is what I've come up with so far following some tutorials

```
Sub Test02()
    Dim border(1 To 5) As String
    Dim i As Variant

    border(1) = "xlEdgeTop"
    border(2) = "xlEdgeBottom"
    border(3) = "xlEdgeLeft"
    border(4) = "xlEdgeRight"
    border(5) = "xlInsideHorizontal"

    Range("'Timesheet Calculator.xlsb'!Feilds").Select

    For Each i In border
        With Selection.Borders(i)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .color = -2315144
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

I keep getting a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" error on the "With Selection.Borders(i)" line. I'm not sure what data type to use for my array to get around this error.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the array to Long as the border types can be expressed as such.

With arrays, a simple For instead of For Each is quicker.

I also changed the name of the array, just to not be like the command.

Then you use: `Range.Borders(brder(i))`

```
Sub Test02()
    Dim brder(1 To 5) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    brder(1) = xlEdgeTop
    brder(2) = xlEdgeBottom
    brder(3) = xlEdgeLeft
    brder(4) = xlEdgeRight
    brder(5) = xlInsideHorizontal

    For i = LBound(brder) To UBound(brder)
        With Range("'Timesheet Calculator.xlsb'!Feilds").Borders(brder(i))
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = -2315144
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```